# How to prevent spam clicking from firing off events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I was looking at the following codepen and i was wondering how you can stop spam clicking, for example, if you click a lot of times at once, the animation starts messing up.

How can I prevent that from happening? Would simply having a conditional work? I tried it but I couldn't get it to work. 
`if isAnimating = true`

How do i get the animation to keep playing and prevent user interaction, until its finished.

http://codepen.io/Filippo/pen/WvGbJB/?editors=011

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on if you do the animation in javascript or css too?

Comment: I'm assuming so, but more or so interested in the javascript solution.

Comment: Take a look at 'debouncing' or 'throttling'. Example here: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to be agnostic from the fact that the animation is played by CSS or JS, there's only one solution. You must know how long is your animation and use a `setTimeout`. For example :

```
var isAnimating = false;
$('#button').click(function() {
    if (isAnimating) {
        return;
    }

    isAnimating = true;

    // Start animation. Add a css class or do this by javascript or whatever

    // Assuming the animation duration is 2 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
        isAnimating = false;
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I like this, this is what I was aiming for. Also realized this animation uses velocity and looks like it has a call back for `complete` when the animation finishes. I can use that to set the isAnimating state. Awesome.

Comment: For your codepen example, the animation is 1000 ms, so here is the updated [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKjyaV?editors=011#0).

Comment: This might sound dumb but if something caused the performance to drop would this not work due to the timing being off?

Comment: @Dane Maybe if the animation is played by CSS. But in pure javascript the timing will be good.

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out how this works, it just does. But the code is not self explanatory to me. Would you mind explaining it?